# Haskell analogous functions (Maybe)

Tags: haskell

I have to implement a function `maybemap`

It has (analogous to the function map) a function

```
f :: a -> b
```

It should apply on a list type `Maybe a` and give out a list `Maybe b`

```
maybemap :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
```

How would I define the `maybemap` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simplest solution, it is, as it mentioned,

```
maybemap :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
maybemap = map . fmap
```

But in general it is more general function:

```
maybemap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> [f a]  -> [f b]
```

As we see, list is also a functor, so we can rewrite

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> g (f a)  -> g (f b)
fmap2 = fmap . fmap
```

And test:

```
> fmap2 (++"!") [Nothing,Just"u"]
[Nothing,Just "u!"]
```

**UPDATED**

The most funniest in `fmap2`, that `(.)` is also a Functor for `a -> b` functions, and `fmap` is a function with same signature: `f a -> f b`. And our function could only consists `fmap`s:

```
fmap2 = fmap fmap fmap
```

Comment: And as `(r ->)` is also a functor with composition as `fmap`, you could write `fmap2' = fmap fmap fmap` which has the same signature as `fmap2`.

Comment: @kqr But I can't easy use it, `(fmap fmap fmap) (++"!") [Nothing,Just"u"]` throw an error.

Comment: Then you must have made a typo (or something else that I'm missing is wrong) because the exact line you wrote in the comment works for me.

Comment: @kqr I have `No instance for (Functor ((->) ([Char] -> [Char])))`

Comment: @viorior It works for me, if I just ask GHCi the type of `fmap fmap fmap` I get `(Functor f, Functor f1) => (a -> b) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)`, which is exactly the type signature of `fmap2`.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks! I found, I used GHC 7.4.2 instead of new one and had `(Functor f1, Functor f, Functor ((->) (a -> b))) => (a -> b) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)`

Comment: Is `fmap fmap fmap` the equivalent of `fmap f a <*> b`? Also equivalent to `fmap . fmap`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `fmap . fmap` is the same as `fmap fmap fmap`. But `(*)` is Applicative function. You could try `> :t \f a b-> fmap f a <*> b` and see the result `:: Applicative f => (a1 -> a -> b) -> f a1 -> f a -> f b`

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `Maybe`'s functor instance, which is defined as follows:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -- fmap's type for Maybe
fmap f Nothing  = Nothing
fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
```

Using this, your function can be defined like this:

```
maybemap :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
maybemap f = map (fmap f)
```

Comment: In short, `maybemap = map . fmap`. Or in fact, `maybemap = fmap fmap fmap`... hey, haven't we seen that one before?

Comment: Thank you! What's the sense of this function? HOw can I proof if it works?

Comment: This was a question in Ch.19 Will Kurt's Get Programming in Haskell but I see it takes two functions to complete the task.